# Google Earth Engine: checking if ee.List() object includes a specific element

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to include ee.List.contains() in a conditional if statement, perform something similar to the following operation, but am getting some unexpected results. In the following code, `test.contains(1)` returns **false**, however if(test.contains(1)) seems to be returning **true**. Can anyone explain why this is occurring and recommend an alternative approach?

```
var a=5
var b= 3
var c=2
var test=ee.List([a,b,c])
print(test.contains(1))
if(test.contains(1)){print('yes')}
else {print('no')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ee.List` is a server-side object, so you cannot use it in regular if-else statements. Look [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) from more details. While you typically try to avoid it in your scripts, you can do this:

```
print(ee.Algorithms.If(test.contains(1), 'yes', 'no'))
```